# JPQL to filter by OneToMany relationship that uses a join table

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to write a JPQL to fetch `Users` with some `Roles` by filtering by `Role.Name`.

```
public class User 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "UsersRoles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "UsersId", referencedColumnName = "UsersId")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "RolesName", referencedColumnName = "Name")})
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Role {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 50)
    private String name;
}
```

I tried the following on @Query in the jpa repository

```
SELECT U FROM User U INNER JOIN Role R WHERE R.name = ?1
```

But that is not working and it generates sql like the following.

```
select 
...
from Users user0_
       inner join Roles role1_ on
where role1_.Name = ?
```

The joining condition is not added.

Comment: The SQL looks fine, the JOIN is there. What SQL were you expecting?

Comment: The join has no condition. It's invalid

Comment: Try: select u from user u join u.roles r where r.name = ?1. It's weird the jpql generate a invalid SQL query...